# React-Native Native Module Object Rendering on Android (iOS)

Tags: android, react-native, module, devexpress, native

I'd like to use native modules like those from DevExpress (charts) to be rendered in react-native.

Is this possible at all?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it is possible. Check out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android. This should at least get you started on Android.

Comment: great! thanks this pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't knot about DevExpress, but if you can use it in Android and iOS, it's possible to render it in React-Native.

Comment: yeah. thanks it works like a charm.

Comment: can you explain how did you solved it ?